Image editing Photoshop
guys!
I need a little help with editing a photo/document. I don't have the necessary tools or skills to do this, so any help would be super welcome!
If you can help, contact me here or send me a private message to arrange. I am willing to collaborate in the best possible way and thank you in advance for your attention and kindness! 
Thank you very much! 

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you have a question, you need to post it here in its entirety if you want advice - including showing what you have tried, or what you need help with.  We are keen to help beginners here - even if you have no clue where to begin, we can still give you some advice. However, please note that there is no way to private message users. Please also check our guidelines on what you can ask about here. Also note that asking for free work is off-topic, also GDSE is not a recruitment agency. Thanks.
